# Comparing Two Excel file with python: 1st-find the difference; 2 highlight it

Tags: python

Hi guys i have two excel files that i want to compare.

1. For example: If i want to compare two files(see below) where sales and profit for id 1 is different in those files, how can i find the difference in python?

   ```
   File 1
   Id   Sales  Profit
   1    100    5
   2    200    20
   3    300    15

   File 2
   Id   Sales  Profit
   1    80    10
   2    200    20
   3    300    15
   ```
2. Also i wish to highlight the difference so it can be compared to last years sales and we know where the difference is coming from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think,if you put data of two excel file into same sheet, then comparing will be 
 easier.

If you compare them in python, `xlwt` and `xlrd` are what you needed. Of course, you can use `pandas`, but it's will be more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `difflib` from [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/difflib.html). Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6LpUklgGHo) how to use it.

> **class difflib.HtmlDiff**
>
> This class can be used to create an HTML table (or a complete HTML
>   file containing the table) showing a side by side, line by line
>   comparison of text with inter-line and intra-line change highlights.
>   The table can be generated in either full or contextual difference
>   mode.